# How do I install linux-tools for a mainline kernel?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, updates, 22.04

I have kernel `5.19.2-051902-generic` on ubuntu 22.04.1 jammy and need linux-tools-generic. However the version that is downloaded after `sudo apt-get install linux-tools-generic` is `linux-tools-5.15.0-58-generic` which is not what i need. So what should I do to get right version of linux-tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have installed an unsupported `5.19.2-051902-generic` kernel.

Ubuntu repositories don't have `linux-tools` for that version.

You need to get `linux-tools` from the place where you got the Linux image.

If it is not there, you can compile it from source.